# How to read data from UITextField located in custom UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsstring, uitextfield

First of all I know there are several more titles looks like same. I have checked them but what I ask is a specific problem.

**What I want to do:** Created Login table which includes email and password. UITextfields in        UITableView. Just want to take those data into some NSString variable pointers for further process.

I have a Custom Cell Class named CustomCell, as below:

```
#import "CustomCell.h"
#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"

@implementation CustomCell
@synthesize textfield;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        textfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 7, 160, 20)];
        textfield.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        textfield.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
        [self.contentView addSubview:textfield];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:NO animated:NO];
    // Configure the view for the selected state.
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

And I have ViewController where I use the custom table below you may see my tableView cellForRowAtIndex method.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    [tableView.layer setCornerRadius:10.0];

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];}

        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                cell.textfield.placeholder = @"Email";
                break;
            case 1:
                cell.textfield.placeholder = @"Password";
                cell.textfield.tag = 0;
                break;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

And lastly below in same class I am trying to read email & password with

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
CustomCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; // ERROR!!!
NSString *userpassword = cell.textfield.text;
```

**Error:** Unknown receiver type tableView:

**Attention in same line:**
ClassMethod +cellforrowatindexpath not found return type defaults to id.

Did you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please ignore the tag in tableView cellForRawAtIndexPath method.

Comment: Why ignore the tag? It's actually not a bad idea to use tag here. Tag your email textfield 1 and password textfield 2. Make your view controller the delegate for both of these text fields and implement `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField`. In this method read the tag to distinguish which text field ended editing. Grab the value and save it in the controller ivar. I'm not typing this as an answer, because I think the real answer to your question should be **Don't use table view if you don't need to display tabular data**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; // Add This instead
NSString *userpassword = cell.textfield.text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your ViewController inheriting UIView or UITableViewController? This is assuming you are calling tableView on the same controller as the Table View.

Answer (score 0):

Yu can't use tableView outside the datasource and delegate methods. What's the name of your tableview in your interface definition? Use that one.